# Gtk.TreeView fails to add a custom renderer with assertion 'gtk_cell_area_has_renderer (area, renderer)' failed

Tags: treeview, gtk, gtktreeview

I'm trying to add dynamically custom CellRenderer to my [Gtk.Treeview](http://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.TreeView.html) with by calling [set_attributes](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.TreeViewColumn.set_attributes):

```
    private void add_column (TrackColumns type) {
        var column = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn () ;
        column.title = type.get_title () ;
        var renderer = type.get_cell_renderer () ;
        column.set_attributes (renderer, "text", type) ;

        view.insert_column (column, -1);
    }
```

Unfortunately, it fails with the error

```
assertion 'gtk_cell_area_has_renderer (area, renderer)' failed
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to call `Gtk.TreeViewColumn.pack_start` before assigning the renderer.

Here's the working code:

```
    private void add_column (TrackColumns type) {
        var column = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn () ;
        column.title = type.get_title () ;
        var renderer = type.get_cell_renderer () ;
        column.pack_start (renderer, true);
        column.set_attributes (renderer, "text", type) ;

        view.insert_column (column, -1);
    }
```